# How to connect correctly MP3 Jukebox Module to make the push buttons work

Tags: circuit-analysis, switches, audio, breadboard, mp3

I purchased the [MP3 Jukebox module](https://www.velleman.eu/products/view/?id=417492) ([manual](https://www.velleman.eu/downloads/0/modules/usermanual_vm202n.pdf)) from Velleman (ref. VM202N).

I have some trouble making the connections on my breadboard.

Here is what I think is the best I can do:

[image]

The result is that the music plays correctly (it is amplified too much by the power amp though, given my 8 Ω, 0.5 W speakers), the LED is blinking together with the input level, but the push buttons don't do what they should do:

1. None of the buttons connected to a resistance really works
2. The only push button connected without a resistance doesn't do the "previous song" action. Instead, it lowers the volume if I keep it pushed, and, when released, the volume goes back to max.

My only guess so far would be that I should use reversed buttons, but it doesn't work either when I try to fake reverse behavior (using my finger to hold the buttons down, and removing one of them to trigger a "click").

I don't want to rush into buying new buttons if the error is elsewhere.

PS: The values of the resistors are correct. I double-checked multiple times.

- The purple wire connected to the "-" (blue lane) on the schematic is the GND corresponding to wire 3 in the manual.
- The grey wire connected to the "+" (red lane) on the schematic is the KEY corresponding to wire 2 in the manual
- The white wire connected to the led (3rd column from left) on the schematic is the LED corresponding to wire 1 in the manual.
- All the push buttons on the schematic have their left pin connected to the red lane (KEY) and the right pin connected either directly (center button) to the blue lane (GND), or with an intermediate resistor (left button and right button).

The purple, grey, and white color coding is visible on the pics below, specially on the second one.

Here are some more pics:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please show a schematic of how your buttons and resistors connect to the module. Please also provide a link to the document that explains how the "key" input works on the module. Pictures show nothing really. So much more is shown in a schematic.

Comment: basic datasheet/brochure: https://quasarelectronics.co.uk/manuals/velleman/datasheet_vm202n_uk.pdf - the "key" wiring is shown in the bottom-right. Although I hate these products that don't provide proper datasheets, it *does* show the needed external wiring.

Comment: There's probably nothing wrong with the buttons themselves. What value resistors did you use?

Comment: I added written explanation of the schematic to help make the parallel with the manual's description, @Andyaka

Comment: @user253751, I used the resistors that came with the kit, namely one 15kOhm (was 14.8 on my multimeter) for the "prev" button" and one 33 kOhm for the pause button (was 32.4 on my multimeter). If it's not the resistors nor the push buttons, could it be the power supply? I'm not so sure how much I should put. I tried 9V for the jukebox (with the adapter) and 12V for the amp, but that gives the same results if I only put 6V for the amp, or if I remove the adapter and provide only 5V for the jukebox module... I'm a bit confused.

Comment: It all sounds okay to me. You wired it the way it said.

Comment: For the voltage, the brochure says 5V or 9-12V (I don't understand why it is not 5-12V) so it seems like you have the right voltage.

Comment: Then what can I try? On the website, it says that the product is discontinued and replaced with what looks like a pretty similar one... Could it be that this version was faulty? I guess my next step would be to e-mail directly the support at Velleman, right?

Comment: I don't know. This is not an infrequent problem with modules like this - they say to wire it like this, you wire it like this... and it just doesn't work right... and nobody has any idea why. Because nobody knows anything about the module the answer ends up just being "get a different module and hope that one works". There's no harm to email Velleman, but I don't know if they'll answer. You can try.

Comment: hang on, I lied, I noticed something. Can you double-check that the key and LED wires are really connected to 1,2,3 and not 4,5,6? I can't quite tell all the colours in the picture but it looks like it might be 4,5,6.

Comment: yes, it's white = 1, grey = 2 and purple = 3. Then, blue=4 and green=5 are not connected to anything, as per the manual. Then, on the other extremity of the breadboard, yellow=6, green=7 and blue=8 are connected to the amp's audio in with the dupont wires brown, white, brown.

Comment: Should I somehow connect the green=7 (gnd) together with the purple=3 (gnd too) ?

Comment: In your last photo, it looks like the gray wire to the top switch is not connected to the switch - it is between the two switch pins.  Use your ohmmeter to make sure you are connected to the right terminals of the switch.  To be sure you are using the switch contacts, use diagonally-opposite pins on the switch.

Comment: @PeterBennett here's the mnemonic for remembering which ways tactile switches connect: see how they have pins that line up on opposite sides? *that's one pin that goes straight through*

Comment: @PeterBennett, the switches are working. I tested the resistances with and without pushing the buttons. Also, I realized one major thing which may make this question irrelevant: the picture of the PCB on all pages of the Velleman website (manual included) don't match the picture I took. The circuit is slightly different, and hence, user253751 might be right: maybe the numbering is wrong too.